# How to handle missing VAT from VAT registered Chinese company selling stock in the UK

Tags: hmrc

A while ago I came across a Chinese company selling 3D printers direct from their warehouse in the UK, not via a 3rd party marketplace. On their website, the seller gives a UK VAT number. The guidance from HMRC (https://www.gov.uk/guidance/vat-and-overseas-goods-sold-directly-to-customers-in-the-uk) seems pretty clear, stating

**Goods that are in the UK at the point of sale**
*If you are an overseas seller who owns goods of any value that are located in the UK at the point of sale you must register and account for VAT on any sales you make directly to customers in Great Britain or Northern Ireland.*

If an invoice from the seller does not include a VAT amount, on the basis that their prices **should** include VAT, would it be reasonable to in good faith reclaim VAT regardless? If it turns out that they are not reporting VAT to HMRC, despite their VAT number, I assume that would be an issue between HMRC and themselves, and the VAT shortfall would be recovered by HMRC through fines to the Chinese company.

Answer (score 1):

### You cannot claim VAT without a valid [VAT invoice](https://www.gov.uk/charge-reclaim-record-vat/keeping-vat-records)

> You cannot reclaim VAT using an invalid [invoice](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/record-keeping-for-vat-notice-70021#vat-rules), a pro-forma invoice, a statement or a delivery note.

If you want to claim the VAT, go back to the company and ask for a valid invoice.

Comment: Indeed, and I had already sent them that exact same guidance page. I suppose I should report them to HMRC if they refuse to provide an invoice with VAT on it because they would then be dodging VAT as they meet the criteria for VAT collection.